# How can I get number of objects in section, NSFetchedResultsController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, nsfetchedresultscontroller

How can I get number of objects in section of an NSFetchedResultcController in Swift?

```
    if let s = self.fetchedResultsController?.sections as? NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo {

    }
```

is giving me `Cannot downcast from '[AnyObject]' to non-@objc protocol type NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo`

```
 var d = self.fetchedResultsController?.sections[section].numberOfObjects
```

gives me `does not have member named 'subscript'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to cast `self.fetchedResultsController?.sections` to an `Array` of `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` objects:

```
if let s = self.fetchedResultsController?.sections as? [NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo]
```

Then you can pass the `section` to the subscript and get the number of objects:

```
if let s = self.fetchedResultsController?.sections as? [NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo] {
    d = s[section].numberOfObjects
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the currently accepted answer by Mike S was pre Swift 2.0

The following is working for me (Swift 2.1):

```
if let sections = fetchedResultsController?.sections {
    return sections[section].numberOfObjects
} else {
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have in my `UITableViewController` (Swift 4):

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else { return 0 }
    return sections.count
}
```